# How can I ignore whitespace changes when doing a SharpSvn merge?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I have the following code and would like to do a merge while ignoring whitespace changes:

```
string folder2 = @"c:\folder";
Uri uri2 = new Uri("http://repo/branch");
ICollection<SvnRevisionRange> mergeRevisions = new Collection<SvnRevisionRange>();
SvnRevisionRange revRange = new SvnRevisionRange(2, 3);
mergeRevisions.Add(revRange);
var mergeArgs = new SvnMergeArgs();
client.Merge(folder2, uri2, mergeRevisions, mergeArgs);
```

Comment: did you check the `SvnMergeArgs` if there is a matching property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from royalTS I found that the following works well:

```
mergeArgs.MergeArguments.Add("-b");
```

or

```
mergeArgs.MergeArguments.Add("-w");
```